# IE getElementbyId not working

Tags: html, vba, internet-explorer, getelementbyid

I'm trying to click 'a' element on a webpage and I can't find out why it does not work.

Here is my VBA code.

```
Function answer1(ie3 As InternetExplorer, str_anwer As String, answerid As String)

Dim ie4 As New InternetExplorer
Dim a As Object


Set ie4 = ie3


ie4.Document.getElementbyId("view=" & answerid).Click
ie4.Document.getElementbyId("reply_cont").Value = str_anwer



End Function
```

Error: Property  not found

Here's the HTML code from the webpage I think it is located in

```
<tr>
        <td class="thm">208975260</td>
        <td><pre>교환</pre></td>

        <td class="subject"><a href="#" onClick="return toggleDetail('208975260');" id="view208975260">작동이안되서 교환 원합니다 어떻게 하면되나요?</a></td>
        <td class="id"><span class="thm">st******</span><br>한혜진</td>
        <td class="thm">2016.09.29 12:53:57</td> 

            <td id="date208975260"><span class="point2 ls1">미답변</span>
            </td> 
        <td class="ansr">-</td>
    </tr>
```

Sorry for my English

I'm not fluent English.

Please, let me know why it is not working

Comment: In `getElementbyId("view=" & answerid)` the `=` should not be there. The result should be `id="view208975260"` not `id="view=208975260"`.

Comment: thanks. i fixed it but not working....     ie4.Document.getElementbyId("view" & answerid).Click
 erro:Property not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Without* reference to *Microsoft Internet Controls (SHDocVw)* and *Microsoft HTML Object Library* the code could look something like the following. Note the `IsNull` call. When `getElementbyId` is called like this and the element is not found on the page this function returns `Variant\Null`.

In commented code a second example is shown. In this case the references were added and `getElementbyId` was called on variable of type `HTMLDocument`. Here in case the element was not found on the page this function returns `Nothing`.

```
Sub main()
    Dim ie, url, readyStateComplete

    readyStateComplete = 4
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ie.Visible = True

    url = "your-url"
    ie.navigate url

    While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> readyStateComplete: DoEvents: Wend

    answer1 ie, "<anwer>", "208975260"

    ie.Quit

End Sub

Function answer1(ie As Variant, str_anwer As String, answerid As String)
    Dim a As Object
    If Not IsNull(ie.Document.getElementbyId("view" & answerid)) Then
        ie.Document.getElementbyId("view" & answerid).Click
    End If

    If Not IsNull(ie.Document.getElementbyId("reply_cont")) Then
        ie.Document.getElementbyId("reply_cont").Value = str_anwer
    End If

'    Dim htmlDoc As HTMLDocument
'    Set htmlDoc = ie.document
'    If Not htmlDoc.getElementbyId("reply_cont") Is Nothing Then
'        htmlDoc.getElementbyId("reply_cont").Value = str_anwer
'    End If

End Function
```

Read about difference between [Early/Late Binding](http://word.mvps.org/faqs/interdev/earlyvslatebinding.htm).